# Getting the process user name in C in Windows

Tags: c, windows, process, pid

I am writing a C program and I need to know the User name of a process using its pid. Is there a way?

I have written the following code:

```
int pid = getpid();
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
```

The value of hProcess comes as NULL;
I need the user name of the process, which I can also see in the task manager. 
(The top process).

The screenshot of the task manager is also attached.
[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW0gI.png)

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I am unable to find a solution in C. I am able to do it in C++/C# but due to language restrictions I can only use the C language. I have the pid of the current process using the getpid() command, but I need the user name of the process.

Comment: @nikhilsid so how do you do it in C++?

Comment: You are probably le looking for the [`GetUserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx) function. If you are able to do it in C++, then you are able to do it in C, and if not, tell us why, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: If `OpenProcess` is returning `NULL` that means the call failed.  You need to call `GetLastError` to find the error code.  The most likely causes are that the process ID isn't valid or that your process doesn't have access rights to the target process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Normally, though, a process should have permission to look at its own information, should it not?  And using the result of `getpid()` implies that the process being opened is the current process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, good point.  Looking more closely, the process in question is `w3wp.exe` (part of IIS) so the most likely problem is that the user's code is running in the context of an impersonation token.

Comment: (Or perhaps the entire process is running with reduced privilege.)

Comment: nikhilsid, have you tried GetUserName as Michael suggested?  Any particular reason you were using OpenProcess rather than GetCurrentProcess?

Answer (score -2):

please try this code

```
const char *getUserName()
{
  uid_t uid = geteuid();
  struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(uid);
  if (pw)
  {
    return pw->pw_name;
  }

  return "";
}
```

Comment: *return pw->pw_name;* Don't return a pointer into the `struct password` returned by `getpwuid()`.  Per [the POSIX standard for `getpwuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html):  *The returned pointer, and pointers within the structure, might be invalidated or the structure or the storage areas might be overwritten by a subsequent call to `getpwent()`, `getpwnam()`, or `getpwuid()`. The returned pointer, and pointers within the structure, might also be invalidated if the calling thread is terminated.*

Comment: Besides which, neither geteuid nor getpwuid exist on Windows in the first place.